# Remove duplicates parentes and children array nested

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects nested in JS and I would like to remove duplicates parents and children.
For example, from this:

```
{
"data": [
    {"label": "A",  
        "children":[
            {"label": "A1"},
            {"label": "A2"}
        ]
    },
    {"label": "B",
        "children":[
            {"label": "B1"},
            {"label": "B2"}
        ]
    },
    {"label": "A",  
        "children":[
            {"label": "A1"}
        ]
    },
    {"label": "B",
        "children":[
            {"label": "B1"}
        ]
    },
    {"label": "C" }         
]
}
```

Would become in a new array with no parents and children duplicate:

```
{
"data": [
    {"label": "A",  
        "children":[
            {"label": "A1"},
            {"label": "A2"}
        ]
    },
    {"label": "B",
        "children":[
            {"label": "B1"},
            {"label": "B2"}
        ]
    },
    {"label": "C" }         
]
}
```

Is it possible?

thanks

Comment: what's the rule to know which children do we need to keep ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? Also, would you like to merge the children (i.e. if you have one A with A1, A2 and another A with A3, should the result child list have A1, A2 and A3?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to, uh, reduce the current data array into a new one with no duplicates:

```
const noDupes = result.data.reduce((noDupesArray, currentItem) => {
  // Check if the current item already exists in noDupesArray.
  const parent = noDupesArray.find((parent) => parent.label === currentItem.label);

  if (parent) {
    // Set parent.children to an empty array if the parent has no children but the current item has.
    if (!parent.children && currentItem.children) {
      parent.children = [];
    }

    currentItem.children.forEach((currentItemChild) => {
      // Check if the current item's child exists in parent.children.
      const childExists = parent.children.some((child) => child.label === currentItemChild.label);

      if (!childExists) { // Push the child to parent.children if it doesn't exist yet.
        parent.children.push(currentItemChild);
      }
    });
  } else { // If current item doesn't exist yet, push it to noDupesArray.
    noDupesArray.push(currentItem);
  }

  return noDupesArray;
}, []);
```

```js
const result = {
  "data": [{
    "label": "A",
    "children": [{
      "label": "A1"
    }, {
      "label": "A2"
    }]
  }, {
    "label": "B",
    "children": [{
      "label": "B1"
    }, {
      "label": "B2"
    }]
  }, {
    "label": "A",
    "children": [{
      "label": "A1"
    }]
  }, {
    "label": "B",
    "children": [{
      "label": "B1"
    }]
  }, {
    "label": "C"
  }]
};
const noDupes = result.data.reduce((noDupesArray, currentItem) => {
  // Check if the current item already exists in noDupesArray.
  const parent = noDupesArray.find((parent) => parent.label === currentItem.label);

  if (parent) {
    // Set parent.children to an empty array if the parent has no children but the current item has.
    if (!parent.children && currentItem.children) {
      parent.children = [];
    }

    currentItem.children.forEach((currentItemChild) => {
      // Check if the current item's child exists in parent.children.
      const childExists = parent.children.some((child) => child.label === currentItemChild.label);

      if (!childExists) { // Push the child to parent.children if it doesn't exist yet.
        parent.children.push(currentItemChild);
      }
    });
  } else { // If current item doesn't exist yet, push it to noDupesArray.
    noDupesArray.push(currentItem);
  }

  return noDupesArray;
}, []);

console.log(noDupes);
```